# String Validation after input or raw_input in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, validation, input

I'd like to test an inputted string against certain conditions. In this instance, I want the string from the variable to contain at least one numeric character...

```
while any(inputted.isdigit()) == False:
    print ("Inputted must contain at least one numeric character") # can't figure this one out
    inputted = input("Please enter a combination: ")
```

An ideal input would be a string like "Boat88Sea"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please give an example of what kind of inputs you are giving? What is a typical example of what is in `inputted`

Comment: An ideal input would be a string like "Boat88Sea"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must iterate over the input string:

```
input_string = "" 
while any(c.isdigit() for c in input_string) == False:
    print ("the input string must contain at least one numerical character") 
    input_string = input("Please enter a combination: ")
```

The moment any character in the string is found to be a digit, the while loop will exit.

Alternatively, this might read even closer than what you want:
As long as not any character is a digit in the input string...

```
while not any(c.isdigit() for c in inputted):
```

Comment: you don't need the square brackets, you can just use a generator instead of a list.

Comment: Correct, thank you; I changed it - but I doubt it makes much of a difference, it is unlikely the input will be large.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely better way than this :

```
cond = True
while cond:
    print ("Inputted must contain at least one numeric character") 
    inputted = input("Please enter a combination: ")
    for x in range(0,9) : 
        if str(x) in inputted : cond = False
```